# Amazon S3 upload with not showing secret key in frontend

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-s3

I'm getting crazy uploading something to Amazon S3... I've been reading a lot about this but I can not be able to make a single upload.

Question is Is It possible to POST a file to S3 through AJAX with not showing secret amazon s3 key?

In almost all examples and tutorials I read, this key was required for building request signature...

I follow next example to get pre-signed URL for amazon s3 which I'll use to post file in my JS: http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/1539/direct-browser-uploading-amazon-s3-cors-fileapi-xhr2-and-signed-puts/

I don't know where I'm mistaken: If I'm wrong in backend or POLICY_JSON in js...

Anybody knows some good working tutorial to follow for uploading file to my amazon s3 bucket?

Thank you for all support

Comment: You shouldn't be "showing" the secret key to the browser if it's in your PHP file; if you don't want to __define__ it directly in your PHP file, then define it in a configuration file and get your PHP script to read it from that file

Comment: Thank you for answering... I've been testing a lot of examples and They get policy and signature request with secret key (such as http://blog.tcs.de/post-file-to-s3-using-node/) How can I make a POST file with well-generated policy and signature request in JS?

Comment: If it's in js, then it will be visible to browsers, so it can't be maintained as a secret: that's why I always do my uploads to my webservers and then have a script on the webserver that pushes to S3: that way, the secret is only available to my PHP scripts, not to the front-end js

Comment: Ty Mark, So It is impossible to make JS S3 FILE POST with no key-secret... Can We calculate sign and policy into PHP script and send It with AJAX? My app requires POST files in clients, because there will be a lot of upload files needs...

Comment: sorry to dig this up, but it's very much possible to post to S3 without secret on client. Option1: Create a static Policy with distant expiry, this is not very secure as the policy can be used outside of your app. Option2: generate a Policy on server (with secret key on server + proper expiration) and send policy to client to use in POST

Comment: @VincentDeSmet do you have a code example/link for this? Sounds like a good solution to this issue, I'm working on the very same right now.

Comment: your API can return a policy object (expiration, acl, bucket, content-type,.. and signature) which is signed by server [see here sample python, java, ruby code for server side signing](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/#signyours3postform) and [sample angular client](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#amazon-aws-s3-upload) + sample [gist](https://gist.github.com/so0k/66d5a592f803cd178b50)